# ZFS on top of LUKS partitions

Tags: linux, zfs, luks

I have weird problem I cannot quite explain.

I have three hard disks. One is the root disk sda, and then there are two more, namely sdb and sdc. The latter have two LUKS partitions sdb1 and sdc1 and I use them in a ZFS pool (just mirrors).

Basically, everything works; however, sometimes the names sda and sdb get mixed up by Linux, so after I boot, I should build the ZFS pool from sda1 and sdc1 instead of sdb1 and sdc1. I can create the LUKS partitions, but then I cannot mount the partition, because ZFS complains with an I/O error. I am extremely surprised that ZFS is not oblivious to the original partition names, and does not only care about how the LUKS partitions that are used are called.

To fix this, I decided to use LUKS UUIDs instead, but this gives the same error. I don't know what to do now; I keep on rebooting my system until sda and sdb name the correct disks and then everything works, but I am obviously rather annoyed by now.

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me with this issue. Probably it's something easy, but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution to this issue is to add the disks by id(s), that is

```
 ls -l /dev/disk/by-id | grep sda | head -n1
 ls -l /dev/disk/by-id | grep sdb | head -n1
```

And you will see pointers to the disks. On my system, `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id | grep sda` yields -

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-id | grep sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 19 15:36 ata-ST95005620AS_5YX07EY0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 19 15:36     -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 19 15:36 ata-ST95005620AS_5YX07EY0-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 19 15:36 ata-ST95005620AS_5YX07EY0-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 19 15:36 scsi-SATA_ST95005620AS_5YX07EY0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 19 15:36 scsi-SATA_ST95005620AS_5YX07EY0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 19 15:36 scsi-SATA_ST95005620AS_5YX07EY0-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 19 15:36 scsi-SATA_ST95005620AS_5YX07EY0-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 19 15:36 wwn-0x5000c5002aa74475 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 19 15:36 wwn-0x5000c5002aa74475-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 19 15:36 wwn-0x5000c5002aa74475-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 19 15:36 wwn-0x5000c5002aa74475-part5 -> ../../sda5
```

Your's will be different, but for example `/dev/sda1`; I would add -

```
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST95005620AS_5YX07EY0-part1
```

Comment: Thank you Elliott, that did the trick.  To tell the whole story, the partitions were even more mixed up... (sdb->sdc,sdc->sda) I think that this was also the problem why it did not work with the UUIDs.

Comment: Use the `/dev/disk/by-id`, it's stable!

Comment: I did, but I had to find out before that sdb and sdc got switched. :-) ... and thanks again!